# PHP/Swifmailer: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with smtp gmail

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have this **function.php**:

```
<?php
require_once '..\vendor\autoload.php';
function format_email($info, $format)
{
//grab the template content
$template = file_get_contents('../signup_template.' . $format);

//replace all the tags
$template = preg_replace('{USERNAME}', $info['username'], $template);
$template = preg_replace('{EMAIL}', $info['email'], $template);
$template = preg_replace('{KEY}', $info['key'], $template);
$template = preg_replace('{SITEPATH}', 'http://site-path.com', $template);

//return the html of the template
return $template;
}

//send the welcome letter
function send_email($info)
{
//format each email
$body = format_email($info, 'html');
$body_plain_txt = format_email($info, 'txt');

//setup the mailer
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
    ->setUsername('xxxxxx@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('xxxxxx');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject('Welcome to TravelNow');
$message->setFrom(array('xxxxxx@gmail.com' => 'TravelNow'));
$message->setTo(array($info['email'] => $info['username']));
$message->setBody($body_plain_txt);
$message->addPart($body, 'text/html');
$result = $mailer->send($message);
return $result;
}
```

and in another php file, I use the **send_email** function:

```
$info = array(
               'username' => $username,
               'email' => $email,
               'key' => $key);

                //send the email
                if (send_email($info)){...}
```

But then I got this error:

[image]

I have already turned on "Allow less secure app" in my Google account, but it's not the error code "535", so I don't think Google security check is the problem here.

Any ways to fix this problem? And I don't really have to stick with Google, should I change to another SMTP service? (example?)

// **SOLVED**:

in **php.ini** search for **;extension=php_openssl.dll** and remove the semisecolon